# if $S$ is a ring with no proper left ideals, then either $S^2=0$ or $S$ is a division ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, division-ring

I am reading Hungerford's Algebra in Chapter 3(Rings), and I am stuck on the following question.

if $S$ is a ring (possibly without identity) with no proper left ideals, then either $S^2=0$ or $S$ is a division ring.

I have found the same question here: [if $S$ is a ring (possibly without identity) with no proper left ideals, then either $S^2=0$ or $S$ is a division ring.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244742/if-s-is-a-ring-possibly-without-identity-with-no-proper-left-ideals-then-ei)
However, I think his proof provided had some flaws and I cannot fixed it.

Here is what I have reached:

If for any $c$, $d$ in $S$, $cd = 0$, then $S^2 = 0$ obviously holds.

Otherewise, exists $cd \ne 0$, then after some proofs we can get that for all $c$, $d$ in $S$, $cd \ne 0$. Morover, right cancellation in $S$ holds, for any $a \in S$, $b \in S$, $\exists x$ such that $xa = b$. And we can get a right identity as what [if $S$ is a ring (possibly without identity) with no proper left ideals, then either $S^2=0$ or $S$ is a division ring.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244742/if-s-is-a-ring-possibly-without-identity-with-no-proper-left-ideals-then-ei) shows. But in the proof of that link, I cannot find a way to get a left cancellation law.

I have some possible approaches to continue: 1. prove right inverse of every element exists; 2. prove the right identity is just the left idnetity.

Can anyone help me with this question? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I solve it: from every $e_id = d$ we can get a right identity $e_i$, so we could only try to prove every right identity are the same. And this is obvious since $\{a \in S | Sa = 0\} = 0$.

Comment: How about [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3541715/29335)

Comment: @rschwieb Nice, thanks a lot!