# Simple commutative rings without identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is the following correct??

> Let $R$ be a nontrivial commutative ring *without* identity. If $R$ has no nontrivial ideals, then $R=\mathbb{Z}a$, for some $a\in R\setminus \{0\}$ such that $a^2=0$.

*Attempted proof.* For every $a\in R\setminus \{0\}$, we have its principal ideal $(a)=Ra +\mathbb{Z}a$, where $Ra\subsetneq (a)$. But, in a commutative ring, $Ra$ is also an ideal. Therefore, since $R$ has no nontrivial ideals, it must be $(0)=Ra\subsetneq Ra +\mathbb{Z}a=R$. Hence, $R=\mathbb{Z}a$ and, by $Ra=\mathbb{Z}a^2 =(0)$, we have $a^2=0$. $\square$

I can't seem to find errors, but if we start from $b=2a$ and the same reasoning would give us $R=\mathbb{Z}b$, but this would result in $a\notin R$, which seems a contradiction. What did I miss?? Thanks.

**Update:** It seems the issue is with the assertion $Ra\subsetneq (a)$ without justification.

If $a\notin Ra$, then follow the above proof and we would eventually get $R=\{0, a, \cdots, (p-1)a\}$, where $p$ is prime and $a^2=pa=0$.

Suppose $a\in Ra$. Then, $(0)\subsetneq \mathbb{Z}a\subset Ra=(a)=R$, and there exists $r_a\in R\setminus \{0\}$ such that $r_a a=a$. But $r_a\in R=Ra$, hence there exists $r_a'\in R\setminus \{0\}$ such that $r_a=r_a' a$. Then, $r_a^2=r_a r_a'a=r_a ar_a'=ar_a'=r_a'a=r_a$ is an idempotent.

Consider $S_a:=\{s\in R: r_a s=s\}$. Since $R$ has no identity, $S_a\subsetneq R$. Otherwise, $r_a$ would be an identity. Note, for $s_1,s_2\in S_a$, we always have $r_a(s_1+s_1)=s_1+s_2$ and $r_a(s_1s_2)=(r_as_1)s_2=s_1s_2$. So $S_a$ is a subring. Also, for every $r\in R$ and $s\in S_a$, $r_a(rs)=r_a(sr)=(r_as)r=sr=rs$. So $S_a$ is also an ideal. Hence $S_a=(0)$. But this is a contradiction, since $S_a\ni a\neq 0$.

Therefore, the correct result should be $R=\mathbb{Z}_p a$ with $a^2=pa=0$ for some prime $p$.

Comment: Any non-trivial ideal of a commutative ring can be seen as a non-trivial commutative ring without identity. For example, the ring $\;2\Bbb Z\;$ . Also if that statement is true then $\;R\;$ must have nilpotent elements...

Comment: @DonAntonio Now it seems to me my last paragraph doesn't introduce a contradiction. It might just mean such an $R$ must have characteristic $2$. But I need to check if there are counterexamples.

Comment: Why $Ra\subsetneq (a)=R$?

Comment: @user760 if $a\notin Ra$, then $Ra=(0)$. If $a\in Ra$, then $Ra=R$.

Comment: @user264745 I came up with a justification for that assertion. Does everything work now?

Comment: You don't have to have $2a=0$, take any prime $p$ and consider $R$ the ring with underlying group $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ with all products $0$, then indeed every nonzero element generates $R$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to point out that there is no need to quote the lemma mentioned above because the ideas in the OP's work on the question are sufficient to resolve it:

If $R$ is a commutative ring with no proper ideals, then if $a \in R\backslash\{0\}$ is any nonzero element of $R$ both $Ra$ and $\langle a \rangle = \mathbb Za + Ra$ are ideals in $R$, and
$$
0 \subseteq Ra \subseteq \mathbb Za +Ra \subseteq R.
$$
Since $\mathbb Z.a \neq 0$ by assumption, we must have $\mathbb Za+Ra = R$ and either $Ra =0$ or $Ra = \mathbb Za +Ra = R$. But if $Ra=R$ then in particular we must have $a \in Ra$ so that there is some $s \in R$ with $sa=a$. But then if $x \in R=Ra$ we may write $x = ta$ for some $t \in R$ so that $sx = s(ta) = t(sa) = ta = x$, and $s$ is an identity element for $R$.

It follows that if $R$ does not have a unit we must have $Ra =0$, whence $R = \mathbb Za$ and $a^2 \in Ra=\{0\}$, that is, $R$ is a cyclic group made into a ring by equipping it with the zero multiplication. Since the multiplication is zero, any abelian subgroup of $\mathbb Za$ will be an ideal of $\mathbb Za$, hence we must have $\mathbb Za = \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ as an abelian group for some prime $p$.

Comment: Why use dot for multiplication? Anyway your proof is correct.

Comment: No reason, to be honest so I've removed them.

Comment: Is it also true Char$(R)$=2? Or did I get that part wrong?

Comment: I mean, if $R=\mathbb{Z}a$, then $2R=2\mathbb{Z}a$ would be a proper ideal, unless $2a=0$. So that should be right.

Comment: Just revised my answer -- $2a$ need not be zero, you just need $(R,+)$ to be a simple abelian group (e.g. in characteristic $3$ you have $2a+2a=a$ so $2a$ generates $R$ just as $a$ does).

Comment: @krm2233 Thanks! So that "contradiction" only proves $R$ cannot have characteristics 0. Then due to simplicity, it must be a prime.

Comment: @user760: exactly! Once you know that $R =\mathbb Z.a$ with the zero multiplication, it follows that $R$ is a cyclic group on the generator $a$, and any subgroup is a subring.  Thus for any $n$ we must have $n\mathbb Za=0$  or $\mathbb Za$.  This is the same as saying $\mathbb Z.a$ is a simple abelian group, hence it must be $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

We will make use of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/244742/861687) lemma. If $S$ is a ring (possibly without identity) with no proper left ideals, then either $S^2=0$ or $S$ is a division ring. In particular, if $S$ is a ring without identity and no proper left ideals, then $S^2=0$.

Since $R$ has no multiplicative identity, $R^2=0$. That rule out the possibility of $Ra=R$. Thus $Ra=0$. You have proved for $Ra=0$ case.

Comment: Great!!! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the commutative case is simpler.